# Check for a condition within an array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, conditional-statements

I would like to check a condition inside an array and perform an operation on the position where the condition is met. For example, this piece of code does the job:

```
res = somefunction(x)
for i in range(x.shape[0]):
    for j in range(x.shape[1]):
        if not 6 < res[i,j] < 18:
            x[i,j] = float('nan')
```

But I thought a faster (and shorter) way would maybe be something like this:

```
x[not 6 < somefunction(x) < 18] = float('nan')
```

But python gives the error that condition checking doesn't work in array with more than element. Is there a way to make my code go faster?

Comment: `x[~((6 < x) & (x < 18))] = np.nan` may work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `not` or chained comparisons with arrays, since neither `not` nor chained comparisons can be implemented to broadcast.

Split the chained comparison into two comparisons, and use `~` and `&` instead of `not` and `and`, since NumPy uses the bitwise operators for boolean operations on boolean arrays:

```
x[~((6 < res) & (res < 18))] = numpy.nan
```

Comment: Okay, didn't see this when I posted. Will remove.

Comment: You should also include that `x` should either be float or object for this to work.